# Is it possible to get error message in bash while debugging in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, bash, debugging, crash

How can I get the `error` message in external `bash script`, when device is connected and app is running from `Xcode` debug mode and a crash happens? For example, while running, the app gets crashed and xcode showing below logs,

[image]

Now I want to get or extract the string from the xcode log at the time the crash happened. i.e. below message,

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ...

And then I want to run an script on that error code/message. Is there any way around?

#### My intention (off-topic),

My intention is to get results from web crawler regarding the crash and to show up to the developers as hint in a dialog.

Photo reference: [codewithchris](https://codewithchris.com/xcode-errors/#detailederror)

Comment: the stack in printed in the logs

Comment: @Vyacheslav yes but I want the asserted error message to pass in an external bash script.